# GPUs visible from normal environment, but not from Docker container

Tags: docker, pytorch, cuda

I’m building a Docker image from a very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update --fix-missing && \
        apt install python3-pip -y && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
WORKDIR /test
COPY ./docker_entry_point.sh .
# entry_point just launching bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker_entry_point.sh"]
```

I tried running the container with either:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged img_name:latest
docker run -it --rm --gpus all img_name:latest
```

but in both cases, the command torch.cuda.device_count() shows 0 GPUs.

From the container, I tried running nvidia-smi, but I got:

```
bash: nvidia-smi: command not found
```

while nvcc --version returns:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

I also tried running:

```
ls -l /dev/nvidia*
```

in the container, and I got:

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/nvidia*': No such file or directory
```

On the same machine, I have a conda environment with:

```
torch              2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio         2.0.1+cu118
torchvision        0.15.1+cu118
```

and from this environment I can access the GPUs without issues. Any clue what I’m doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you followed the [documented](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#access-an-nvidia-gpu) steps of installing the Nvidia Container Runtime?

Comment: I didn't do it myself because I'm working on a server managed by my company, but it seems to be working for other people.

Answer (score 1):

`nvidia-smi: command not found`
suggests that CUDA must be (re)installed.